# Using the Maximum Modulus Principle to prove that every holomorphic function on a compact Riemann surface is constant

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces

I have read in a number of sources (including here) that a holomorphic function on a compact Riemann surface must be constant. The reason given has always been the Maximum Modulus principle, but without explaining why. I could use some help in proving this result.

Comment: There are two issues that I don't understand:  why must S be open and why f must be an open map if it is non-constant?

Comment: I think your question is about my answer. If this is the case, note that it is actually possible to comment underneath my answer. If you leave a comment under an answer, the user who answered gets a notification.

Comment: I have written out the argument that $S$ is open. The fact that a nonconstant holomorphic map is sometimes called the [open mapping theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_mapping_theorem_(complex_analysis)). The link only states it for an open subset of $\mathbb{C}$ but it holds more generally. Namely, if $M$ and $N$ are Riemann surfaces and $f : M \to N$ is a non-constant holomorphic map, then $f$ is open.

Answer (score 7):

Let $\Sigma$ be a connected compact Riemann surface, and let $f : \Sigma \to \mathbb{C}$ be a holomorphic function.

As $|f| : \Sigma \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and $\Sigma$ is compact, it attains a maximum value $M$. By continuity, $S := \{p \in \Sigma \mid |f(p)| = M\}$ is closed.

Suppose $q \in \Sigma$ is such that $|f(q)| = M$. Let $(U, \varphi)$ be a coordinate chart centred at $q$. That is, $U$ is an open neighbourhood of $q$ and $\varphi : U \to \mathbb{D}$ is a biholomorphism with $\varphi(q) = 0$. Consider the map $f\circ\varphi^{-1} : \mathbb{D} \to \mathbb{C}$. Note that $(f\circ\varphi^{-1})(0) = (f\circ\varphi^{-1})(\varphi(q)) = f(q)$, so

$$M = |f(q)| = |(f\circ\varphi^{-1})(0)| \geq |(f\circ\varphi^{-1})(z)|$$

for all $z \in \mathbb{D}$. By the Maximum Modulus Principle, $f\circ\varphi^{-1}$ is constant, and therefore, $f$ is constant on $U$. So for any $z \in U$, $f(z) = f(q)$ and hence $|f(z)| = |f(q)| = M$. Therefore $z \in S$ and hence $U \subseteq S$, so $S$ is open.

As $S$ is both open and closed, and $\Sigma$ is connected, $S = \Sigma$. That is, $|f(p)| = M$ for every $p \in \Sigma$, so $f(\Sigma) \subseteq \{z \in \mathbb{C} \mid |z| = M\}$.

Finally, use the fact that if $f$ were non-constant, it would be an open map which is impossible.

---

*Note, this proof does not make use of the identity theorem, but it does use the open mapping theorem (i.e. non-constant holomorphic maps are open). Alternatively, one could give a proof which uses the identity theorem, but not the open mapping theorem. Namely, once it has been shown that $f$ is constant on $U$ (as is done above in the proof that $S$ is open), it follows immediately that $f$ is constant by the identity theorem. Both proofs require the Maximum Modulus Principle.*

Comment: Thank you for your tip on leaving comments.  This is my first time using any SE. You have given an elegant proof & I finally understand it.  I have concluded that your script D is the unit disk centered at z=0.  I believe that your final conclusion that f being open is impossible is because the image of f is a closed set.  However, I don't see why f must be open if it is non-constant.

Comment: That is exactly what $\mathbb{D}$ denotes. A non-constant holomorphic map between Riemann surfaces is open, this is a separate result sometimes called the open mapping theorem.